# WCF service, change HttpStatusCode depending on return value

Tags: wcf, rest

I have a WCF Service that exposes two endpoints. One with a `WebHttpBinding` (acting as a REST service for mobile clients) and one with a `NetTcpBinding` (used for desktop .NET clients)

Let's say that a client accesses the service method `GetData`. If there is no data I will return ´null´ (or `false` or ´0´ depending on what has been called). If the client is a mobile client accessing the `WebHttpBinding`-endpoint, I would like to change the `HttpStatusCode` to something other than OK.

Is there a way of doing this and still keeping my service implementation general (not putting any http-specific code there)? I know that I can use `IDispatchMessageInspector` to intercept the message and change the status code, and only do this for the `WebHttpBinding`-endpoint, but then I wouldn't really know what to change the status code to...

Is there anyone who has a suggestion as to how I can solve this?

**Update:**

I'm starting to think that there really is no way to do this in a nice way, since the only place I actually really know what when wrong is in the service implementation.

Comment: Just my opinion: The HttpStatusCode should only reflect the status of the http transmission and not deal with the content.

Comment: Is there any rule you have for determining when to change the status code? I.e., if the return value is null/0/false, you'd **always** change it? Or is it something dependent on the operation?

Comment: @Filburt, I kind of agree with you there, but it's a request from the guys developing the mobile client that they want to know why they couldn't get the data they wanted to

Comment: @carlos, I've been thinking about that as well. But it is depending on the operation, and returning false doesn't have to be a "negative" answer. At the moment I'm just setting the `WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.StatusCode` and `WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.StatusDescription` in the service implementation, independent of what endpoint the call came through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit: the nice way:** Seperation of concerns (SoC). The REST implementation only adds REST concerns to the service and inherits the base implementation which does the whole business logic.

Comment: Thank you, but I'm already aware of that. My problem is that I want to differentiate between calls made on different endpoints. If the call is made on the REST-endpoint, then I'd like to throw an exception (which will set the status code). If the call is made on the other endpoint, then I do not want to throw the exception, just return null

Comment: Could you have your REST-endpoint set to a specific REST implementation of your service? Are you asking for the code to determine the endpoint type at runtime?

Comment: That's what I'm trying to avoid. I don't want separate implementations, but the more I think about it, I think that is what I will have to do to make it work like this.

Comment: Honestly, I think it's the way to go: seperation of concerns (SoC). The REST implementation only adds REST concerns to the service and the base implementation (your other endpoint) does the whole business logic. Convince yourself. Hope it helps. :)